# How can I get the minor currency unit?

Tags: go, currency

Golang has the currency package (https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/text/currency) which includes formatting. It is not obvious though how I could format something in minor (Cent) instead of major (Euro) units?

See: https://go.dev/play/p/0CQUOIjaeKM

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "golang.org/x/text/currency"
)

func main() {
    eur := currency.EUR
    amt := eur.Amount(0.28)
    fmt.Println(amt)
}
```

This outputs:

```
EUR 0.28
```

But it should be:

```
28 ct
```

Comment: Provide [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: How should I provide an MRE if I can‘t find the docs to achieve what I want?

Comment: Post working compilable Go code, output you get and desired output.